# CFWheels social networking screencast example

Tags: coldfusion, cfwheels

I'm trying to run the social network example from the screencasts. I'm using CF 11. I'm running Apache with XAMPP in Windows 7. I get the congratulations message when I go to localhost/wheels. I also copied the wheels directory to wheelstest, and that works as well. Did that as a sanity check.

I downloaded the source for the example from

https://github.com/cfwheels/Social-Network-Screencast

I put the code in a directory called snet (s(ocial)net(work)). I created the wheels_demo database and persons table using phpmyadmin. Then I went to the CF Admin screen and created a data source pointing to the database.

When I go to loclhost/snet, I get a nasty looking page with: "Adobe ColdFusion 11,0,0,289974 is not supported by Wheels."

The comments at the bottom of the github page refer to a plugin called dbmigrate. I downloaded and unzipped the source for that, and I get "Could not find the included template ../../wheels/global/functions.cfm."

I'm a bit stuck here. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Couple of things here:

1) it might be the latest patch of cf11 isn't recognised by wheels yet - either way, you'll want to try with the 1.3x release if you're not already.

2) Running cfwheels in a sub-directory usually means you have to make some changes (I don't do it myself, so can't remember what) - think it's to do with the URL rewriting. "Could not find the included template ../../wheels/global/functions.cfm" is almost definitely to do with that.

3) DB migrate doesn't work with 1.3x I think.

Comment: Well, wheels is definitely working -- I get the wheels congratulations page, hello world works, etc. But I'm running 1.3.1, so that might be the dbmigrate problem.